# Error when creating a parameter in Parameter Store that stores an ImageID of an AMI built in the same Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I receive this error when running the cloudformation template:
CREATE_FAILED: Stabilizing the parameter creation for parameter /GS/web:1

Below is the code for the resource creation of the parameter and the policies, both in the resources section:

```
- PolicyName: SSMCreation
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - ssm:DescribeParameters
            - ssm:AddTagsToResource
            - ssm:GetParameter
            - ssm:GetParameters
            - ssm:GetParametersByPath
            - ssm:GetParameterHistory
            - ssm:PutParameter
            - ssm:LabelParameterVersion
            - ssm:DeleteParameter
            - ssm:DeleteParameters
          Resource:
            - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/*"

SSMImageParameter:
Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
Properties:
  Type: String
  DataType: aws:ec2:image
  Name: /GS/web
  Value: !GetAtt CustomImage.ImageId
```

Comment: Can you provide full template? What is `CustomImage`?

Answer (score 1):

Add a waitCondition to imageCreation Lambda

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitcondition.html

Image creation will take a while and SSM parameter creation may happen before ImageId is available (lambda creation would succeed and dependency will succeed but has to happen after custom lambda executes)

Comment: This shouldn't happen because there is already a dependency set using `!GetAtt CustomImage.ImageId`.

Comment: @Marcin Thats right, however, in this case, Image is getting created and there is no AWS CFT resource to do so. It has to be a custom resource and it has to be wait handle, updated the answer